# How to wait for a function to execute by all components of flatlist?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to solve this in a much elegant way but I feel the code currently is pretty messed up. So I have a parent component that contains a Flatlist and a button. The Flatlist contains child components that have checkboxes, on press of the button, I want to check which checkboxes in my Flatlist are ticked. The way I tackled this problem was by passing down a prop into the child component. This is how my parent FlatList and state looks -

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      getAllVendorDetails: 0, //This state is to trigger an event(by 
      incrementing) in the child checkboxes to send the ticked vendors to 
      this parent component.
    };
  }


<FlatList
    data={this.state.vendorsToPick}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <SelectVendors getAllVendorDetails= 
    {this.state.getAllVendorDetails} pushData={(item) => 
    this.addVendor(item)} vendorData={item}></SelectVendors>}
    horizontal={true}
    extraData={this.state.getAllVendorDetails}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
/>
```

On press of the button, I increment the state **getAllVendorDetails**, which triggers a rerender in my child component and in componentDidUpdate I push the component that has its checkbox ticked, to the parent, as a parameter through a prop - Which inturn calls a function in the parent component that adds these items to an array. All this works perfectly fine, I get all the ticked checkboxes on press of the button. (Maybe there's a better way to do this, idk).

I want to perform an operation ONLY after i've received all the items that have a ticked checkbox in my array, I dont know how I could achieve that, currently I have a delay of 500ms after pressing my button, and then if I check my array, I have all the ticked checkbox items. But for sure there has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: I think using redux to store which checkboxes are checked will be helpul in your case since the delay of 500 ms can be removed.

Comment: That's a good idea, that would give me certainty as well. Thanks for the suggestion!